# How do I create methods for a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, methods

I'm writing an android application. 
In the main thread, it is possible to define methods and then call the methods, which helps keep the code clean. In a new thread, how does one define methods, to avoid writing all the code in "one block"? Is it possible to call methods defined in the main thread, or can you define them inside the new thread somehow? 
So to be clear, what I want to do is this:

```
    volatile Runnable feedToBuffer = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() 
{
    if(boolean)
    {
    MethodA();
    }
    else
    {
    MethodB();
    }
}
```

and not this:

```
volatile Runnable feedToBuffer = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public synchronized void run() 
    {
        if(boolean)
        {
        //Code that was in MethodA
        }
        else
        {
        //Code that was in MethodB
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible?
I realize this info is probably out there somewhere, but haven't found it, so really grateful for any help. :)

Comment: Yes, of course, that is possible. The `run` method is just a normal method, it can call other methods as well.

Comment: Just defined those methods after the run()... `new Runnable(){ /* here I can create every methods I want*/ }`

Comment: It is weird to have a `synchronized` run method. Why did you add that?

Comment: Just a note, depending on the logic you are going to put in this Runnable, consider declaring a Class inheriting it.

Comment: Maybe you want to synchronize the methods called inside the run method, not the run itself.

Comment: Thanks Thilo and AxelH!! I will try that right away. : ) I probably added the synchronized because I was trying to use methods defined in the main thread and didn't really understand what 'synchronized' meant. ; )

Comment: Yes, that works! AxelH comment was what solved my posted problem, so if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: haha, this is so nice - you have no idea how much this will clean up my code. : ) My thread had about 2000 lines of code without methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible. Thread is just a sequence of actions, and if it involves a method call, it will be executed within that sequence. It doesn't matter.

Threads are in no way tied to the structure of your code. The main difference between the threads you start and the one you have already when the app starts is the points of entry. When Android starts the main thread, it enters your app in many points, in the activity that would be the lifecycle calls like `onCreate()` or button click listeners. When you create a new thread, your point of entry is the `run` method from where you can call anything you want.

There is also a difference in that the main thread runs an event loop. Basically, there is a queue of messages that it has to process. Each time something arrives to the queue, it processes the message, then goes back to waiting. In that sense the main thread never ends. Your thread, however, stops when it reaches the end of the `run` method. Of course, you can implement a similar event loop for your thread yourself.

Other than that there are no fundamental differences in how the threads operate, you can call methods from any thread freely. Of course, there are rules of multithreading like avoiding blocking the main thread, synchronization, and so on, but it's too much to cover in one answer.

Comment: So basically, I can call a method from main, as long as I don't try to do it before it has had time to be defined or at the same time a different thread is trying to use it? That is good to know, I will go with defining the methods in the thread separately for this case since it seems safest, but will check into synchronization - seems important. : )

Comment: @gnyrfta You can call the same methods simultaneously if they don't modify anything. If they do, then you'll need to be aware of the synchronization to write correct programs. I'll refer you to [Oracle's concurrency tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). You really need to read them, otherwise you will probably write incorrect code which may work fine most of the time, but then unexpectedly fail. For something more advanced I advise you to read Java Concurrency in Practice, it's a very useful book.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at that.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as answer, but if someone runs into the same problem as me - also note AxelH comment above on where to define methods inside  the thread.  It really helped me.

Comment: @gnyrfta He suggested that you can create methods inside the anonymous class, but this doesn't really have anything to do with multithreading in particular, it's more of a question of code organization. If you have some operations specific to the `Runnable`, then it does make sense to do that, but nothing prevents you from creating the methods somewhere else if they need to be called from outside the `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my specific case I do have methods that only need to be called in the Runnable and not in the rest of the code. The concurrency tutorials were good stuff btw.